# Which domain do I need to whitelist as an HTTP referrer for Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I am using MaxCDN for my website, and to prevent hotlinking, I only allow my website's pictures to be displayed on whitelisted HTTP referrers, through MaxCDN's security settings.

However, even though I have added every kind of Google domain I could find, my post's pictures won't show up in new Google+ Posts.

[image: Google+ no Image]

These are the domains I have whitelisted so far:

```
*.googleusercontent.com
*.google.com
*.googleapis.com
*.gstatic.com
*.googlegroups.com
*.ggpht.com
```

Which server am I missing?

Comment: What do your logs report?

Answer (score 1):

Google+ doesn't hotlink images. It fetches images directly from Google's servers and services cached versions to users so I doubt there will be a referrer. You might try whitelisting user-agents that contain `Google`.

Comment: I understand that Google+ doesn't hotlink. The same happens with Facebook, and I had to whitelist *.akamai.net and *.akamaihd.net for it to work. But for the life of me I can't find anything similar for Google.

Also, MaxCDN won't let me whitelist *google* or anything like that. It must be *.domain.com

Comment: You probably have to whitelist a *user-agent* header not the referrer header, although MaxCDN might not let you whitelist on that.

Comment: Yes, they probably won't let me. It's a good service, but not very flexible in this kind of thing.

Comment: Google will also publish a list of the ip addresses their bots use.  Try searching for GoogleBot Ip addresses.